# How do I add an ID to a menu entry to GRUB config?

Tags: boot, grub2, configuration, bootloader

I want to add an ID to any menu entry in the Grub config and then auto generate the configuration by changing `/etc/default/grub` file

```
DEFAULT_GRUB = desired_linux_version
```

I already did but grub still loads the latest Kernel.

```
$ uname -a 
4.4.0-28-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 10:09:13 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The config generated  (`/boot/grub/grub.cfg`) has this line:

```
set default="gnulinux-4.4.0-21-generic-advanced-80006992-e4de-4bf4-9b4f-08e22d8a40fe"
```

Comment: Sorry, what ID are you talking about?

Comment: Any ID,  custom or the default ID as I tried : gnulinux-4.4.0-21-generic-advanced-80006992-e4de-4bf4-9b4f-08e22d8a40fe @Ron

Comment: so you mean you want to set a specific menu entry as the default entry?

Comment: @Ron Yes, I think I can choose which Kernel will be booted by default if set that way.